# jQuery $.post() and MySQL problem

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using jQuery and $.post(). My code snippet is as follows for chat .php :

```
<?php
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("user");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO space (name,msg,serial) VALUES('Test','$msg','1')");
?>
```

and here is the code for my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Shout!</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var status=1;
function action() {



if(status==1) {
$("#Layer1").hide("slow");
$("#Layer3").hide("fast");
$("#Layer4").hide("slow");
$("#close").attr("src","open.jpg");
status=0;

} 

else if(status==0) {
status=1;
$("#Layer1").show("slow");
$("#Layer3").show("fast");
$("#Layer4").show("slow");
$("#close").attr("src","close.jpg");

}




}


function sendline() {


var msg=$("#msg").val();
$.post("chat.php",{msg:msg});
$("#msg").val(" ");
}

function typeyo() {
var text=$("#msg").val();

$("#Layer6").html(text);

}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #000000;
}
#Layer1 {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:115px;
z-index:1;
left: 199px;
top: 3px;
}
#Layer2 {
position:absolute;
width:69px;
height:64px;
z-index:2;
left: 570px;
top: 543px;
}
#Layer3 {
position:absolute;
width:131px;
height:91px;
z-index:3;
left: 487px;
top: 327px;
}
.style1 {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-weight: bold;
}
#Layer4 {
position:absolute;
width:99px;
height:38px;
z-index:4;
left: 744px;
top: 485px;
}
#Layer5 {
position:absolute;
width:274px;
height:70px;
z-index:5;
left: 422px;
top: 62px;
}
#Layer6 {

width:638px;
height:356px;
z-index:5;
left: 352px;
top: 105px;



}
-->
</style></head>

<body>
<div class="style1" id="Layer3">
<textarea name="textarea" cols="30" rows="5" id="msg" ></textarea>
</div>
<div id="Layer1">Hello World!<img src="body.jpg" width="842" height="559" /></div>
<div id="Layer2"><img src="close.jpg" alt="Go Online/Offline" name="close" width="63" height="64" id="close" OnClick="action()"/></div>
<div id="Layer4">
<input type="button" value="Send Line" onclick="sendline()" /></div>
<div id="Layer6" style="color:white;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:16px;width:500px; height:400px; overflow:auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now,there seems to be some problem posting the variable msg.Im using chat.php for $.post() on the HTML code that i've provided.

There seems to be a problem with sending the "msg" here . The chat.php file is fine since if we run it directly ,and not thorugh a $.post() call it works perfectly

Kindly Help! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your msg variable that you try to send via POST is not initialized,
add the following line at the beginning of your `sendline` function:

```
var msg = $("#msg").val();
```

Note: you have a big/huge security issue inserting variables from POST in MySQL queries without prior treatment.

Comment: yes,i've done that,i'm sorry i forgot to update it on the weblink that i'd provided. It still doesn't work :/

Comment: sorry then hard to help with actual solution if you don't provide with actual code :(

Comment: not :
var msg=("#msg").val();
but :
var msg = $("#msg").val();

Comment: stil no luck :( . Nothing gets inserted into the table :(

Comment: i've tested your page and data is correctly sent now, but i'm wondering if your chat.php script is at the same level as your main page, since http://techknowlegy.iblogger.org/chat.php gets a "403 forbidden"

Answer (score 0):

**update:** I suggest you use a javascript debugger, set a breakpoint at the beginning of  `function sendline()` and step through the code. Which one to use depends on your browser(s).
Firefox -> e.g. [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/)
IE7 -> e.g. [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038)
IE8+ -> just press `F12` to open the developer tools that are shipping with IE.

---

In addition to [darma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435069/jquery-post-and-mysql-problem/3435110#3435110): Your php script is prone to sql injections (intentional/malicious as well as unintentional ones). Either use [prepared, parametrized statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [escape the data](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) properly.

working example:

test.html:

```
<html>
  <head><title>test.html</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sendline() {
        var msg = $('#msg').val();
        // --- add some tests on msg here, e.g. msg=="" ---
        $.post(
          "chat.php",
          {'msg':msg},
          function(data, textStatus, req) { $('#reply').text('reply: ' + data); }
        );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <textarea id="msg" rows="5" cols="30" name="textarea"></textarea>
      <button onclick="sendline()">send line</button>
    </div>
    <div id="reply">&nbsp;</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

chat.php:

```
<?php
// --- add some tests on $_POST['msg'] here
// e.g. isset($_POST['msg']) and 0<strlen(trim($_POST['msg'])) ---

// you might want to use a slightly more sophisticated error handling than "or die(mysql_error())" ...but this is only an example.
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","localonly", "localonly") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $mysql)  or die(mysql_error());
$msg=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg'], $mysql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO space (name,msg,serial) VALUES('Test','$msg','1')";

// mysql_query($sql, $mysql) or die(mysql_error());
echo htmlspecialchars($sql);
```

---

**update2:** You still don't have any error handling in your php script. Any of the mysql_* function can fail for various reasons; test the results. You need to "see" those errors, e.g. by writing them to a log file or something...
Try

```
<?php
define('LOGERRORS', 1);
function dbgLog($text) {
  if (LOGERRORS) {
    error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s : ').$text."\n", 3, 'error.log');
  }
}

if ( !isset($_POST['msg']) ) {
  dbgLog('script called without post parameter "msg"');
  die();
}

$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if ( !$mysql ) {
  dbgLog('database connection failed: '.mysql_error());
  die();
}

$result = mysql_select_db("user", $mysql);
if ( !$result ) {
  dbgLog('database selection failed: '.mysql_error($mysql));
  die();
}

$msg=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg'], $mysql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO space (name,msg,serial) VALUES('Test','$msg','1')";
dbgLog('sending query: '.$sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql, $mysql);
if ( !$result ) {
  dbgLog('query failed: '.mysql_error($mysql));
  die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'd like to know more about function(data, textStatus, req) { $('#reply').text('reply: ' + data); } . I don;t quite understand thisi'm very new to jQUery). Could you please elaborate on this
THanks!

Comment: also,i'd like to know if there's technically any *problem* in my code ? I've used $.post() the way i'd used in my file as given above and it worked perfectly ,but not in this case . Any idea why ?

Comment: You still have `var msg=("#msg").val();` in your code, i.e. missing a `$`. The `function(data, textStatus, req) { }` is called if and when jquery successfully completed the request.

Comment: I'm sorry there's some problem with the server it seems.The page isn;t getting updated. But its still not solving the MySQL problem ... any idea as to why its hapenning ? is my code logically and syntactially correct(ofcourse after making the corrections you pointed out)

Comment: Please update the original question with your current code version. And if for some reason the html code doesn't get updated on your server also include the relevant part of that code. It doesn't make much sense for us to _guess_ what your current version really looks like.

Comment: As i had stated earlier,everything is the same,apart from the corrections that you had suggested.

Comment: I've added my HTML code to my question as per your request. :)

Kindly help!